# How make animation increase of number

Tags: count

On site wordpress display dynamic number use shortcode in wp-editor, like this:

```
[lifetime]
```

Need make animation increase of number. Maximum value number is not known, because number is dynamic.

How make [this animation](http://jsfiddle.net/uvzx0aLg/) increase of number on wordpress?

Comment: Hi. I've created a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2r4yo7oy/1/) for you. Add a class to your shortcodes, and then count it using `.length`.

Comment: thank you for help. i make this http://jsfiddle.net/uvzx0aLg/50/

Comment: You're welcome. I'm confused... How do you set the maximum number? By using `data-target`? And what does `[lifetime]` output?

Comment: `[lifitime]` -  its shortcode contain value of variable - maximum number. i set shortcode in `data-target`. and inside `h4` is start number. hope understand clearly, my english not good)

Comment: Sure, but you can't use a shortcode in JSfiddle to see the results. Replace it with something like 50, and you can see that it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i make this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentNumber = $('.js-number-lifetime').text(),
        targetNumber = $('.js-number-lifetime').attr('data-target');
    $({numberValue: currentNumber}).animate({numberValue: targetNumber}, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() {
            $('.js-number-lifetime').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue));
        }
    });

    var currentNumber1 = $('.js-number-clients').text(),
        targetNumber1 = $('.js-number-clients').attr('data-target');
    $({numberValue: currentNumber1}).animate({numberValue: targetNumber1}, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() {
            $('.js-number-clients').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue));
        }
    });

    var currentNumber2 = $('.js-number-employee').text(),
        targetNumber2 = $('.js-number-employee').attr('data-target');
    $({numberValue: currentNumber2}).animate({numberValue: targetNumber2}, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() {
            $('.js-number-employee').text(Math.ceil(this.numberValue));
        }
    });
});
```